# SpriteKit cocoa Mac Uses Intel GPU instead of Nvidia on MBP

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, sprite-kit, gpu

Developing My Cocoa SpriteKit game on my MBP.

When I profiled the Game with Instruments GPU driver section
it shows IntelHD 5000 in driver column.

However when I minimising the Game and looking in to "About this mac -> Displays" it shows Nvidia 750m

a) How can I know which one it uses?

b) In case it uses Intel how can I convince it to use Nvidia ?

Comment: This may be what you're looking for https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Preferences, Energy Saver panel there is a Checkbox `Automatic graphics switching`. Set it unchecked to always use the high-performance graphics card. Then in About This Mac menu, the overview tab should show which graphics card is being used.